Automatic display of "x" on equation
I would like to display the regression equation on the plot by using this code:
ggplot(correlation_columns, aes(x=mean_CO, y = `HNA adjusted (particles/m^3)`)) + geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y ~ x, fullrange=TRUE) +
  stat_poly_eq(use_label(c("eq", "R2", "n")), parse = TRUE)

The equation is display but the "x" sign is not showed on the graph. Anyone has a solution?
Data:
library(ggpmisc)
library(ggplot2)

mean_co <- c(0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.2000000, 0.1791667, 0.2041667, 0.2190909, 0.1675000, 0.1958333, 0.1520833, 0.1650000)

HNA_adjusted <- c(841.571609, 127.867016, 1205.266416, 4641.796145, 9414.766992, 747.572996, 99.297126, 402.177504, 377.085391, 84.230400, 7156.367632, 21089.363818, 3463.446762, 6957.162695, 6.447113, 4827.340603)

correlation_columns<- data.frame(mean_co = mean_co, `HNA adjusted (particles/m^3)` = HNA_adjusted)


I can't reproduce your issue. When I run your code with the provided example data I get https://i.sstatic.net/e8QTLXiv.png

There is a typo in your ggplot() code, "mean_CO" should be "mean_co". Also, which versions of ggpmisc and ggplot2 are you using? As with the previous comment, your code produces the desired outcome using  ggpmisc_0.5.6, its dependent ggpp_0.5.7, and ggplot2_3.5.1.
